# Unable to launch tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am unable to import the tensorflow 2.0 module into my code i end up getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Perseus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit [this bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794).

You can downgrade tensorflow to `v1.10.0`

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0
```

or make sure that you have these versions for CUDA, Tensorflow and CUDNN:

- CUDA v9.0
- tensorflow-gpu v1.12.0
- CUDNN 7.4.1.5

Alternatively, you can uninstall tensorflow and install it through conda:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow 2.0 is now officially available. You can retry. This time it should work without any errors, if CUDA and CuDNN are properly installed.